# Does the butterfly keepsake's buff persist after you swap it out?

Tags: hades

One of the keepsakes you can earn in Hades is the Pinned Butterfly, given to you by

> Thanatos

gives you a stacking overall damage buff every time you clear an encounter room without taking damage. For obvious reasons, this becomes steadily harder as you progress, while other keepsakes might have more benefit in higher areas.

Do those stacks persist even if you swap the keepsake for a different one between realms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you lose the benefit from the Butterfly as well as the Lambent Plume if you swap them out for another keepsake. Although the Lambent Plume does have a side benefit of working as a pre-requisite for Hermes' Legendary Boons, so in some cases it can still be worth taking for only one biome, but there's no such thing for the Butterfly.